# How to generate training and test dataset from given standard dataset from UCI

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have a Cancer Dataset with 699 rows and 11 attributes(including class attribute). How can I divide the dataset into training and test datasets?
I know following things. Are they true?
(1) Selecting Initial 150 rows for Testing and remaining 549 for training
(2) Selecting Initial 549 for training and remaining 150 for testing

Further do I need to include the class attributes in both datasets? Is it also necessary to have another dataset called as "VALIDATION DATASET"?
I am doing classification using SVM

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Cancer Dataset with 699 rows and 11 attributes(including class attribute). How can I divide the dataset into training and test datasets? I know following things.
>
> Are they true? (1) Selecting Initial 150 rows for Testing and remaining 549 for training (2) Selecting Initial 549 for training and remaining 150 for testing

None of the above makes any sense for dataset of that size

How such small dataset a single split **is not enough**. You will need multiple splits, using for example:

- cross validation (10 splits should suffice)
- bootstrap methods (like 632+)
- maaaany totaly random splits (>50)

> Further do I need to include the class attributes in both datasets?

Both parst (in each split) have to have labels

> Is it also necessary to have another dataset called as "VALIDATION DATASET"? I am doing classification using SVM

Again, for such small dataset you will not be able to have a good validation dataset (and you need it to select valid hyperparameters for SVM), thus you will have to do **internal cross validation** (or internal bootstraping etc.)